# How to clear the highlighting in VSTO

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, word-addins, word-automation

I am developing a `word addin` in `c#`. I have used the `Find` method to highlight the found search terms. (For background, see [Find and Highlight issue in word addin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50291072/3077495)).

I use the `Find.Execute()` method, but I want to use it more than once. But the highlighted words from the previous search are still highlighted.

How can I clear the old highlighted ranges before running method?

```
 word.Find find = rng.Find;
        find.Wrap = word.WdFindWrap.wdFindContinue;
        //find.Execute(findtext);
        find.Replacement.Highlight = 1;
        Globals.ThisAddin.Application.Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = Word.WdColorIndex.wdRed;
        find.Execute(FindText:wd,Replace: Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll,MatchWholeWord: true,MatchCase: true);
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove highlighting from the body of the document:

```
Word.Document doc = Globals.ThisAddin.Application.ActiveDocument.InnerObject;
doc.Content.HighlightColorIndex = Word.WdColorIndex.wdNoHighlight;
//Now perform the Find
```

Comment: How to remove Underline from the active document using `find.Execute(...)` method ? Wherever the underline is there, it is needed to be removed ?

Comment: Here I don't have the list of words to be passed as a parameter in FindText parameter

Comment: @spidie_sridhar I suggest you ask a new question. You can include a link to this discussion, if you feel it provides important background.